# Draw Rectangle which change size w.r.t different android screen size

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I want to draw a rectangle using canvas which change its size with different screen size.
That means it increase of decrease its size with screen ratio.
 I use the following code:

```
float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
canvas.drawRect(leftX-20*scale, leftY-20*scale, rightX+20*scale, rightY, mPaint);
```

But it does not change its size in different screen.
 What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;` it wil give you same dencity always better use the following approach

To get density Use the following code

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();    
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);    
int screenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
```

so your code will be

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();    
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);    
    float scale = metrics.densityDpi;

canvas.drawRect(leftX-20*scale, leftY-20*scale, rightX+20*scale, rightY, mPaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try

```
float scale= Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
```

This is implemented in my Android Game "MaracasRunner".